# Explain why arbitrary linear operator $T: \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$ has at least one eigenvector in $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The way I'm thinking about it is if $T$ has at least one eigenvalue in $\mathbb{C}^n$, then there must be at least one eigenvector belonging to that eigenvalue. The problem is proving that there has to be at least one eigenvalue.

Comment: Are you familiar with the fundamental theorem of algebra?

Answer (score 3):

Because it has at least one eigenvalue. The characteristic polynomial must have at least one distinct root in $\mathbb{C}$. Unlike $\mathbb{R}$.